# Join two SQL select queries of same table and filter

Tags: php

I have a table of doctors with following columns given below and I am wanting to fetch details by date using the submit button. But I can't filter the queries for details of the same table. I am converting the date to specific day and storing it in `$day` variable and the id in `$available` variable through transferring the value of session variable from previous page and implementing it in two SQL queries. Can anyone please guide me? I am sorry for any typing mistakes.

Doctors:

```
  id  doctorname    date1       day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7
  1    arvind     2018-05-29   
  2    sonal      0000-00-00    mon   tue  wed  thu  fri  sat  sun
  3    harry      0000-00-00    mon   tue  wed  thu 

 <?php
   session_start();
   include 'connect.php';
   if(isset($_GET['submit'] ))
   { $date=$_GET['date'];
     $available= $_SESSION['available'];  
     $day=date('l', strtotime($date));

   $sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT id,specilization,doctorName, 
   docFees, starttime, endtime,date1 FROM doctors WHERE 
  id= '$available' AND cast(date1 as date) = '$date'"  )
  UNION
  SELECT id,specilization,doctorName, docFees, starttime, endtime,date1 
  FROM doctors WHERE id= '$available' AND DAY1='$day' OR DAY2='$day' AND
  DAY3='$day' OR DAY4='$day' AND  DAY5='$day' OR DAY6='$day' OR
  DAY7='$day'");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
  If(empty($_GET['date'])) 
  {  echo "ENTER DATE  PlEASE";}   
  elseif($row1>1) 
   {echo "Day:". $day;
     echo "<br>";
     ?>  <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row1['id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row1['specilization'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row1['doctorName'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row1['docFees'];?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row1['starttime'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row1['endtime'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $_SESSION['bdate'];?></td>

        </tr>
       </table>
       <?php }?>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the question you're asking. I am almost certain however you are using a hammer to crack a walnut with all those queries.  Can you try and explain exactly what you are trying to achieve?  Is the end user just entering a date and then the doctor available for that date and his/her skills are listed?

Comment: Honestly I would do this work in a proc in the database and then just execute it from the webpage. This will be easier to code and also manage.

Comment: You have `UNION` outside the call to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Why are you using both `AND` and `OR` between the `DAYx = '$day'` conditions? I suspect you want something like `'$day' IN (day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, dayy7)`

Comment: hello stephen! i am trying to fetch details of the doctor through date . and the doctors who are  sitting on days i am coverting the date into specific day and matching it with day columns .after that i am writing to sql queries both in case of doctors with date and day and i want that when i am fetching details only for that particular day or date should show doctor with specific id otherwise the column should display nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `UNION`, just use `OR`:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"
    SELECT id,specilization,doctorName, docFees, starttime, endtime,date1 
    FROM doctors 
    WHERE id = '$available' 
    AND (cast(date1 as date) = '$date'
        OR '$day' IN (day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7))");
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd81ee/6)

Comment: hello barmar thanks for replying .my problem is that suppose some    doctor is booked for 29/05/2018 and when i am fetching for it it is showing doctor details but when i am submitting for that same doctor in 31/05/2015 the details should show nothing but it is showing the details of other doctors is that.same case should be followed for doctors with day .suppose 29/05/2018 is tuesday the doctor with that id should show only on that day .i hope you are getting me.can u plz help me

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you update the question and show some sample inputs and the expected results?

Comment: Ok look in the given table above arvind is available on 29/05/2018.now suppose i am if i am searching for arvind on 29/05/2018 after pressing submit button it should display arvind records.now if i put 31/05/2018 by arvind id it should display nothing or not available. The same thing i want to do with harry who sits from monday to thursday.so if i am taking any date which is from monday to thursday  the date is first converting into specific day and checking with day columns.now harry's  record should display from monday to thursday only and not for friday ,saturday and sunday .

Comment: Put the clarification in the question, not just a comment.

Comment: I was missing a `)` before. I fixed that and added a sqlfiddle demo showing that it works.

Comment: Thanks Barman After 2 weeks i finally got my project complete .you are really genious! it seriously worked!